# View all requests by a Valence app/user

Tags: desire2learn, valence, user-tracking

How do I view all requests from a specific app and match them to a specific D2L user?

Within the D2L database, REQUEST_LOGGING_USERS_PATHS_DAYS shows the requests for each user and EXT_TOKENS shows the user tokens for a specific app. How do I match the requests to a token/app?

For example, the types of questions I'm seeking to answer include: What requests has app x made yesterday? What requests has user y made while using app x?  The above is very important to understand what an app is doing, how often, and the load it's putting on the D2L system (essentially, troubleshooting and performance testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information isn't presented in the user interface or stored as a unit in the database. Self-hosted clients who have access to IIS logs can scrape the logs to find the AppID and UserID for each call and draw some conclusions from that information.

If this is an important set of information for you that you would like to access via a report or similar mechanism, I recommend that you pass that feedback to D2L via the Product Ideas Exchange (https://community.desire2learn.com/d2l/lp/navbars/1796/customlinks/external/15394).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I've created an idea on the PIE: D1973.